# Formating a csv file in Postgrest API REST to insert the data

Tags: csv, import, postgrest

The goal is to select a CSV file on a computer to insert the data in a distant PostgreSQL table using `POST` request.

Once the CSV file has been selected in a html page, a click on a button causes it to be processed in the browser.

```
const btnIntegrer = document.querySelector(".btn-integrer")

btnIntegrer.addEventListener("click", () => {

const fichierCsvInput = document.querySelector(".fichier-csv")
const fichierCsv = fichierCsvInput.files[0]
reader.readAsText(fichierCsv)
let data = ''
let datafinal = ``
reader.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
    data = e.target.result
    const ligneTab = data.split("\r\n")
    ligneTab.forEach( ligne => datafinal += `${ligne}\n` )
})

fetch('http://blabla/testapi?', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "text/csv"
    },
    body: datafinal
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log('insertion réussie:', result)
    } )
    .catch(err => {
        console.assert.error('insertion échouée:', err)
    })
  })
```

I don't know how to deal with the CSV file to get a correct `body` in the `load event` like in the [doc](https://postgrest.org/en/v10.2/api.html#insertions).

I have an error in the console :
`code   "PGRST102" details null hint    null message 'parse error (not enough input) at ""'`
Obviously, there is an issue with `datafinal` but I can't get rid of it.

my original csv:
`num,description 3,bli bli 4,bli`

Answer (score 1):

the problem was that `fetch` is async so `datafinal` was empty. I moved the `fetch` inside the `load` event. Now it is good.